# Cnosdb‘s execution effect of show queries is inconsistent with that of select * from information_schema.queries order by duration limit 3;

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

Cnosdb‘s execution effect of show queries is inconsistent with that of select * from information_schema.queries order by duration limit 3;
pre-require:
cluster is ready;
3meta 3 data;
step：

```
1. show queries;
2. select * from information_schema.queries order by duration limit 3;
```

expect:
The results of the two queries should be consistent;
result：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jphBk.png)